# File Attachment Management for Rails and Oracle Cloud - OCI Object storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rubygems, paperclip, rails-activestorage

Looking for a RAILS solution for OCI Object Storage, we currently are using paperclip on AWS with S3. Paperclip is depreciated and Active storage has no documented solution for OCI Object Storage.

Any solutions or suggestions re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

OCI Object Storage is S3 API compatible, so you can set it up in the same way you would with AWS.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm